# ngClass AND conditional expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
ng-class="{'blue': item==1, 'blue': !item}"
```

I expect I will have class blue if my item is not set or item equal to one but it doesn't work that way.

Comment: You can't have different keys with the same name in an object literal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*blue if my item is not set or item equal to one*

You need to use `||` operator and define expression as

```
ng-class="{'blue': !item || item==1 }"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may find following code snippet helpful.

```
 ng-class="{ 'active' : CreateCaseModel.CaseTypeId == 2 }
```

In above case, if expression is evaluated to true it will add active class.

replace "CreateCaseModel.CaseTypeId == 2" with your own condition, and it(expression) should return true or false.

ng-class="{ 'active' : expression }

Comment: do u understand my question?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work just create one more class containing the same contents as in class blue and use that for second condition. Because `ng-class` doesn't allow to same class to apply for different condition.

Contents of class blue and blue1 are same.

```
ng-class = "{'blue': item == 1, 'blue1': !item}"
```

Comment: @arulkumar Great job. You can write a blog on formatting